# Grasping the concept of P-value

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am having a hard time grasping the concept of the P-value.. 
I've read some of the posts in here and on internet, but one thing seem to be missing for me.

Usually we look at the probability of values being higher than the sample mean, and if this probability is lower than 0.05($\alpha$) it would be rejected, which don't make sense.

The probability says that values above test-statstics the would occur less time, but why would that lead to rejection of null hypo?

as it is stated a lot of places

> In technical terms, a P value is the probability of obtaining an
>   effect at least as extreme as the one in your sample data, assuming
>   the truth of the null hypothesis.

If the probability of getting extreme values are higher than 0.05, then the null hypo will be accepted?.. which makes no sense.

Comment: Made it more precise

Comment: Your final sentence indeed makes no sense, but that's not what the quote above it says.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem.. What didn't make sense was that the meaning of the probability, but it make more sense, since the probability is seen on a normal dist. 

If I could answer it myself i Would do it.

Comment: The p-value is not in general related to a normal distribution.

Comment: Well. yeah but i understand how it works now.